# Extract all the char between 2 strings using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to ask some question Regular Expression in Python.

In the variable nihao, there is a string like the following：

```
Committee Members: Prof.A (Supervisor)
```

I want to extract Prof.A(only the Prof.A, eliminate all the \t or other white spaces) 
between

Committee Members:

and

(Supervisor)in python language.

How should I write the regex?

Thanks.

Comment: "Is it correct to write like this?" Did you try it? Or should we try for you?

Comment: I try it... it seemd failed... The actual point is that I do not know how to write the logic..

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of edits:

- You had Member instead of Members.
- You have to escape the parentheses around Supervisor
- ([\w|.|\s]+) would be a better capturing group.

---

```
Committee\sMembers:\s+([\w.\s]+)\s\(Supervisor\)
```

Look here:
http://regex101.com/r/pS9bQ9/4

Note: Next time, regex101.com is a good website to test your regex's

Comment: Remove unessary `|` in the character class. `\w`, `\s` and `.` are already ORed inside character class.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @VincentBeltman's regex a bit, it can be done like this as well -

```
 # Committee\s+Members:\s*(\w[\w.\s]*?)\s*\(Supervisor\)

 Committee \s+ Members:
 \s* 
 ( \w [\w.\s]*? )         # (1)
 \s* 
 \(Supervisor\)
```